# Issue with iFrame and overflow:hidden in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, iframe, overflow

I am running into an issue that apparently only exists in IE 11. This is for an intranet page. The relevant code is below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" />
    <title>Result</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chatcontent">
            <iframe class="noscrolling" src="intranetsharepoint" target="_blank" scrolling="no"></iframe>           
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**stylesheet.css**

```
body {
    background-color: #F0F8FF;
}
#chatcontent{
    width:20%;
    margin: auto;
}
.noscrolling{
    height: 50px;
    width: 120px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
iframe{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

I have been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out why, in all of the other browsers, the scrollbars disable themselves, but in IE 11 they refuse to sod off in the `iFrame` element. It works just fine when putting `overflow: hidden` in the body, can't scroll anywhere, only seems to not work in `iFrame`. I have tried every variation of `overflow: hidden`, scrolling=no, forcing html 4 via !DOCTYPE declaration, compatibility with older versions of IE, and nothing seems to be working. Any advice at this point would be a godsend. I saw a snippet of code that would have made an `iFrame` out of JS, but I don't understand enough of the language to put it together with what I already have. Any help would be greatly appreciated. It works as intended in Chrome and FF.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an URL in the SRC of the IFRAME make the scrollbars disappear in IE11 (tested).

Comment: Thanks. We were using a `data:image`. Changing it to a png url fixed it for us :)

Answer (score 0):

It may have something to do with the code INSIDE of the IFrame. Try posting that in your question. Also, you can research AJAX for JavaScript, and create a type of IFrame out of AJAX. Like you said before, it IS a bit confusing at first, comment on my answer if you need me to give a complete example. Here is a link to a basic example of AJAX: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp
This will let you get the content of a page, copy and paste it into a div, and make it be a type of IFrame. Then, you can also edit the code of the page, and set the attributes necessary (overflow:hidden) to the div.